# jquery focus function not working

Tags: jquery

i have made one jquery function, in which when we focus on textbox its background color should change, but its not working have a look on my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jQueryv1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('TextBox').focus(function(){

$(this).css('background-color', '#cccccc');

});

});

</script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" meta:resourcekey="TextBox1Resource1"></asp:TextBox>
```

help will be highly appreciate

Comment: Note that `<asp:TextBox>` is an ASP control, it will be rendered to an `input`-tag.

Comment: thanks rob its working, but one issue when i remove focus its background color still unchanged...why this happen

Comment: You will have to make another eventhandler for the `blur` event and set the `background-color` back to it's default value there. I gave an answer which actually solves your problem with pure css so you won't have to use any javascript!

Comment: thank u so much Rob sir you have made it done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: This is not really an answer to the original question, but after reading your comment this solves your situation a lot better!

According to your case, it would even be better to solve this with pure css using the `:focus` selector.

```
input:focus
{ 
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: it means without jquery we can also do that focus effect

Answer (score 1):

**Repalce**

```
$('TextBox').focus(function(){
```

**With**

```
$('#TextBox1').focus(function(){
```

Use Jquery `ID` selector.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$('TextBox').focus(function(){
```

to

```
$('.TextBox').focus(function(){ // class selector
$('#TextBox1').focus(function(){ // id selector
```

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery should go for the class of the control (if the class is what you are planning on using):

Correct syntax: `$('.Textbox').focus(function()`

Answer (score 0):

Please tried based on page configuration

> $('#TextBox1').focus(function(){ // id selector });

If you using MasterPage

> $('#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').focus(function(){ // id selector });